# write a java program that include a function called getVowel() that takes a linked list

Tags: java, algorithm, data-structures, linked-list

Using java.util.LinkedList,  write a java program that include a function called getVowel() that takes a linked list of a type String and returns only the data values that include a vowel letter as the first letter.

Explanation : If the initial data values in the linkkedList are   [Algorithms, Data, Computer, Information]  The Returned values of getVowel() must be only [Algorithms, Information] because they are the only data values that start with a vowel letter such as A in Algorithms and I in Information.

*the function getVowel() does not exist*

```
import java.util.*;
public class g {
    public static void main(String[] argv) throws Exception 
    { 
        try { 

            // creating object of LinkedList<String> 
            LinkedList<String> list = new LinkedList<String>(); 

            // add some elements to list 
            list.add("Algorithms"); 
            list.add("Information"); 

            // print the linked list 
            System.out.println("LinkedList : " + list); 


            String value = list.getVowel();

            // print the vowel of list 
            System.out.println("the vowel of list : " + value); 
        } 

        catch (NullPointerException e) { 

            System.out.println("Exception thrown : " + e); 
        } 
    } 
}
```

Comment: This is your task to implement a method `List<String> getWordsStartingWithVowel(List<String> inputList)`.  You cannot call getVowel() on the instance of a LinkedList from Java Collections.

Comment: Side issue: `catch (NullPointerException e) {...}` -- never do this

Answer (score 1):

You need to write a method (or function) like this:

```
private LinkedList<String> getVowel(LinkedList<String> originalList)
{
    // put your implementation/code here
}
```

Inside the method build and return a new linked list with only the required elements from the original list.

In your `main` method call your `getVowel` method and print what it returns.

Comment: sorry but i dont got it very well, could u please write the code within

Comment: V.V  it not my homework , my friend challenge me

Comment: Will your friend think it’s a good idea I solve the challenge? Maybe you can persuade your friend to drop a comment here?

Comment: i dont wanna lose

Comment: That I clearly understand. Where I come from, cheating a friend is worse, though.

Comment: dont get me wrong! she allows me to search ab it im not cheating though! and she challenged me to solve it but i did not realize it was that hard for a beginner in algorithm

Comment: You can find some inspiration here: [Filtering a list in Java](http://zetcode.com/java/filterlist/). Search for much more.